# Put the specific item at the last loop in php foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want to put a specific element of array at the last loop in a foreach loop.

I did try the following codes, but I hope there is a more efficient way to manipulate the array.

```
$sbk = ['LT','MT','KT','GT'];
$sbl = ['LT','MT','GT'];
$numItems = count($sbk);
$i = 0;
foreach($sbk as $rm){
   if(in_array($rm, $sbl)){
       echo $rm."\n";
   }
   if(!in_array($rm, $sbl)){
       $extra = $rm;
   }
   if( ++$i === $numItems) {
       echo $extra."\n";
   }
}
```

This is my expected output:

```
LT
MT
GT
KT
```

I want the solution to be in the if else condition.

```
foreach($sbk as $rm):
   if(in_array($rm, $sbl)){
      //print LT MT GT
   } else {
     //make this the end of the foreach loop. 
     //since the item is not in the in_array, it should be here at the last loop.
   }
endforeach;
```

Comment: This would have nothing to do with last. You want to get the intersection of values of `$sbk` and `$sbl`. Am I right?

Comment: Or maybe you want uncommon elements to move to last?

Comment: @vivek_23, I want to print 'KT' at the last loop. My solution would not work if I want to store it rather than printing it directly. Yes I want uncommon element(s) to the last loop.

Comment: try to foreach with `$sbl` instead of `$sbk`

Comment: It will not work because I want to print them all. I want to move one element to the last..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php


$sbk = ['LT','MT','KT','GT'];
$sbl = ['LT','MT','GT'];

//Get the differece of sbk and sbl array. you will get the output KT in array.
$result=array_diff($sbk,$sbl);

//Merge the array result and sbl
$final_array = array_merge($sbl,$result);


//fatch the array value
foreach($final_array as $final_arrays){
    echo $final_arrays .'<br/>';
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
$new_array = array_unique(array_merge($sbk,$sbl));
```

Comment: This does not put the 'KT' element at the last loop.